# How to make monitor edges match on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have two screens. My primary screen is a `3840x2160` laptop screen. My secondary screen is a `1920x1080` monitor. The issue I'm having is that due to the screen resolutions, Windows thinks the laptop monitor is ~4x larger than the external monitor, when in reality the laptop monitor is physically smaller.

What I would like is for the left edges of my laptop monitor to match up with the right edges of the external monitor.

How can I do this?

Edit: Without lowering the resolution of my laptop monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natively, you can't get rid of the unaligned edges unless you set the displays to the same resolution, and align the displays (on the side they share) in the display properties.

The program [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) has an option to prevent bumping against edges when moving between monitors at different resolutions, as well as ones that are not aligned exactly.

[image]

I've been happily using DF for years to deal with multiple monitors, and it's handy as heck. :)

Comment: Trying it out and this seems pretty cool. Where do I find this preference though?

Comment: Right-click the icon by the clock > Settings > Window Management. :)

Comment: BTW if you like it, I highly recommend you pay for it (I don't believe this mouse feature is in the 'free' version). It's a one-time cost, and he's been regularly updating it for several years now (latest version was released like yesterday) -- well worth the $25-$35 cash. :)

Comment: This is great, but it can be disorienting as you move towards vertical edges . It would be nice if you could map edge of one screen to edge of the other way in a specific way, so that in real life, when looking at the monitor, mouse moved from one monitor to other would stay at the same height. Going from bigger monitor to smaller would clamp the mouse to the top/bottom when moving from height on bigger monitor that smaller doesn't cover. I know there is a little Github project called LittleBigMouse, but that doesn't work on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your desktop and click ***Screen Resolution***. Then drag and drop the monitors around to let them match what your needs.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. The problem isn't moving the screens around. It's getting their heights to match up.

Comment: Oh, well I'm afraid that requires you to change screen resolutions... @PandaConda

Answer (score 0):

[Continuous Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/continuous-mouse/9p6nts4k5425) is another simple alternative. It allows you to define exactly the transitions between monitors.

I designed this software with efficiency and having multiple monitors in mind.